# Vim Color Scheme behaving oddly in tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

When I set any theme with a dark background in vim, on opening any file in tmux, the background spreads only around the lines having text. (Please see the attached image)
my tmux.conf has `set-option -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"`
and my .cshrc file has `setenv TERM xterm-256color`

[image: vimrc screenshot]

Comment: I have asked a [similar question](http://superuser.com/q/689571/42141) and it got moved to superuser. Which is the correct place for this type of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, this question is answered [here](http://sunaku.github.io/vim-256color-bce.html).

The fix is to disable the **Background Color Erase** Property for the terminal:
`:set t_ut=`